# Why is CPU usage constantly increasing after starting/stopping threads?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a program where on a button's click, a new thread will be created (if it didn't exist already) and a connection to a camera is established. Now consider this same flow, but with N number of cameras (thus creating N threads on click). After the button is clicked again, all of the previously created threads are told to stop executing (through a boolean flag), and then Join(500) is called on each one - ending all threads.

Now, I have noticed that successive clicks performed within a short time interval not only bump CPU usage (normal when the 8 threads are running), but also keep that usage at the same level even after the threads have supposedly ended from the call to Join(500).

What could be causing the CPU usage to remain high even after the threads are joined?

(**Note**: I have also tried the TPL's Task.WaitAll() implementation and observed the same scenario, so I want to say that this is not caused by the threads somehow not stopping execution.)

Edit:

```
Thread[] m_threads = new Thread[8];
void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_threads.Length; i++)
    {
        m_threads[i] = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (m_continue) { ... }
        });
    }
}

bool m_continue = false;
void Stop()
{
    m_continue = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_threads.Length; i++)
    {
        m_threads[i].Join(500);
    }
}
```

Start is called on the first click, while Stop is called on the next click.

Comment: Pretty sure you've created a race condition here... Without code its hard to say, but event handlers may be called from separate threads. `Join`-ing from multiple threads is a bad idea. If you have 8 threads, calling `Join` with a 500ms timeout may take up to 4 seconds to complete since calling `Join` blocks the calling thread until the joined thread completes or times out, then it executes the next `Join` until you exit the method.

Comment: By the way, `Join` does not terminate a thread, nor does it terminate it after the timeout expires. It just waits that timeout then continues running. If the thread doesn't terminate on its own, it will continue to run.

Comment: You should consider a thread-pool instead of creating a billion threads. Having more threads than the amount of processors your computer has is pointless anyway. Which means this turns pointless already after 4-8 threads, since 4 or 8 cores is usually the normal. Of course you could have more, but you should get my point. The .NET thread pool will probably handle this better than yourself trying to do it though.

Comment: @Bauss `Having more threads than the amount of processors your computer has is pointless anyway` this is not generic formula. Say you have 8 threads on a 8 core machine and all of them are blocked by an IO (disk, network etc) operation. A new thread could benefit the idle CPU at that point. If your statement were correct, Thread pool would have only 8 threads on a 8 core machine,

Comment: estebro. suppose you clicked *stop* and while its waiting, you clicked *start* again. start will replace the content of `m_threads`  with the newly created threads. So in `Stop` you may be waiting the newly created threads....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
bool m_continue = false;
```

to

```
volatile bool m_continue = false;
```

According to your description, I assume m_continue gets cached (in a register or whatever) and thus never changes, even when you assign it in Stop() method.